# Geocode in Google spreadsheets, keep results

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form for internships and I am passing over the address of the internship provider to a function which gives me latitude and longitude for it, which is then consumed by a [webmap](http://www.digital-geography.com/praktika-im-geo-umfeld/) using tabletop to leaflet.

The function works like this:

```
function getLat(address) {
  if (address == '') {
    Logger.log("Must provide an address");
    return;
  }
  var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder();
  var location;
  // Geocode the address and plug the lat in the result
  location = geocoder.geocode(address);
  // Only change cells if geocoder seems to have gotten a
  // valid response.
  if (location.status == 'OK') {
    lat = location["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
    return lat;
  }
};
```

My problem: I am only having 15 entries in the result spreadsheet but it gives me already the error `Service invoked too many times for one day: geocode. (line 10, file "Code")`. The function is working for new entries as I am only using `=GetLat(B13)` as an example.

My question: is there a way to store the result of a succesfull function result, like using `=continue(A2,2,1)` instead of copy-pasting of the `getLat`/`getLon` function to the one-hundred rows of the spreadsheet or to prevent the reevaluation of the function after some time?

(You can find the document [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At1v4YI-I7pCdEpqN2phMEt2UEF2U25MejRxU2ktc1E&usp=sharing).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is the correct usage of  project triggers. you can use them to control the webapp to run only on form submit:[image]